# Devise/Google OAuth 2: Not found. Authentication passthru

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I followed the tutorial in the readme of the [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) gem and when I click the link on my root (@ `pages#home`), `<%= link_to "Sign up with Google", user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path %>`, I get the error:

> Not found. Authentication passthru.

I've confirmed the ENV vars are there. I've been looking at similar topics with no luck. Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

In routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, controllers: { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

My omniauth_callbacks_controller is located at `/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
      # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

      if @user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      else
        session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except(:extra) #Removing extra as it can overflow some session stores
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
      end
  end
end
```

In my `devise.rb` file:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], {
      name: 'my-project',
      scope: 'email',
      prompt: 'select_account',
      image_aspect_ratio: 'original',
      image_size: 100,
      ssl_verify: false
  }
```

And in my User.rb:

```
devise :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]

   def self.from_omniauth(access_token)
         data = access_token.info
         user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

         # Uncomment the section below if you want users to be created if they don't exist
         # unless user
         #     user = User.create(name: data["name"],
         #        email: data["email"],
         #        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
         #     )
         # end

         user
     end
```

Comment: Have you considered posting an issue on the GitHub project?  The author may be able to help you.

Comment: I haven't. It's not an issue with the gem, seems like something minor I'm doing wrong.

Comment: are you shure your route `user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path` is OK? what you get with `rake routes | grep omni` ?

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem adding the following to `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = %i[get]
```

Explanation:

the above is the configuration shown in https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#usage :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
end
OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = %i[get]
```

but without

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
end
```

since that is already provided in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], {
      name: 'my-project',
      scope: 'email',
      prompt: 'select_account',
      image_aspect_ratio: 'original',
      image_size: 100,
      ssl_verify: false
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still looking for the answer:

1. Make sure no file `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` in the initializer folder.
2. Use a blank hash at the last config.omniauth argument at `config/initializers/devise.rb` as follow:

```rb
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], {}
```

Or we can use email scope alone. Since it will tell google that we request user details by email `{ scope: "email" }`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding the `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection`:

```
- gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection"
```

And then, the important part:

> You will then need to verify that all links in your application that initiate the OAuth request phase are converted to HTTP POST forms containing an authenticity_token value. This can be achieved by changing all link_to methods to button_to, or by using link_to ..., method: :post.

Initially, I attempted:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in with Google', user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post %> <br />
```

However, what was required was:

```
<%= button_to 'Login with Google', user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post, data: { turbo: 'false' } %> <br />
```

Adding the `button_to` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking that your redirect URI for Google OAuth is correct, and includes `/callback` on the end.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15665920)

Comment: @Iceman - thanks for the feedback, but please do not confuse the _questioning style of the answer_ as _requesting clarification_. The OP has clearly followed the instructions for the gem to the letter, and stated that the env vars have been checked. The redirect URI is one thing that is not included in the documentation, and is a possible cause of this error. So (at least in my mind) it *is* a potential answer... and I've edited it to be more clear that this is in fact, not a question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem like this:

1. I added gem `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` into Gemfile
2. In my view I added POST method

```rb
<%= link_to "Sign in with Google", 
    user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path,  method: :post %>
```

3. In my `devise.rb`:

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = [:post, :get]

  provider :google_oauth2, Rails.application.credentials[:GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID], 
      Rails.application.credentials[:GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET], {scope: "email"}
end
```

4. My routes:

```rb
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"
}
```

More information check this issue:
[enter link description here][1]

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5236

Comment: Welcome to SO. When answering an old question that already has answers, please try to explain why yours is different or is an improvement on the previous answers.