# Devise Oauth Twitter: OAuth::Unauthorized Forbidden 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-twitter

I am trying to implement Oauth Twitter using Devise.
I have created app on twitter
I have set callback url to: **http://localhost:3000**
I have added this to config\initializers\devise.rb

```
  config.omniauth :twitter, "key", "key secret"
```

**Sign in with Twitter** automatically appears at this route: /users/sign_up/
But on clicking it I get this error

key and key secret are correct

I also tried deleting and creating new app.

I cannot get it fixed

Help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

[Here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/403-forbidden-error/2291/6) it says that https needs to be setup.
So I followed [This](http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/rails-on-https) to set it up. But getting the same error

Comment: if I am not wrong your callback url should be like this: `http://www.example.com/users/auth/twitter/callback` and you may want to mention the same in your twitter app settings.

Comment: Also forbidden usually means you are passing wrong credentials. this tutorial could help you figure out the missing part: https://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

Comment: @Abhinay Updated as you said in twitter app settings but didn't work out

Comment: I removed 'config.omniauth :twitter, "key", "key secret"' this line. Instead added to config/initializers/omniauth.rb and that error is gone. But now I am getting 'Not Found. Authentication passthru'

Comment: this question here should resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812844/devise-omniauth-facebook-not-found-authentication-passthru

Comment: @Abhinay Thanks for help. The issue was because of the configurations in twitter app settings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that in twitter app settings **Callback URL Lock** was set to **Yes** by default. Switching it to **No** fixed the error.

[Thanks to kubido for helping me out to close the issue on github](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/issues/128)

Answer (score 6):

You can try to add these in the Callback URLs in https://apps.twitter.com/

- http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback
- http://127.0.0.1:3000/
- http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback

Worked for me after almost an hour!

I got these URLs after failing the log-in. I checked the request_options. One way to do it is using BetterErrors gem.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had been facing the same issue,
eventually i fixed it by adding the following callbacks,

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback
http://127.0.0.1/
http://127.0.0.1/auth/twitter/callback
http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback
```

and it worked like a charm,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need set the callback url to: "Your url"/auth/twitter/callback