# Omniauth-twitter with Rails 5 stopped working! OAuth::Unauthorized 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth, omniauth-twitter

Everything was working fine and Omniauth has stopped working suddenly. I didn't make any code changes.

I checked Twitter Apps Settings:
I have callback url to my main production url, and  Callback URL Locked to  No. All keys are correct.

Any idea?

---

OAuth::Unauthorized

403 Forbidden

[image]

Comment: I also tried to regenerate tokens. Still same issue!

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50560813

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have been able to solve it (also for development) adding this urls:

For production:

- `https://mydomain/users/auth/twitter/callback`
- `http://mydomain/users/auth/twitter/callback`

For development:

- `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/twitter/callback`

Comment: This seems to be the working solution. Works both locally and in production.

Comment: Wow, thanks @antoniobg87! I was missing the users/ part as opposed to just adding auth/twitter/callback. This worked for me in production. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Now on twitter callback URL, you must have to add 2 callback URLs and the callback URL must be the path of your application.

I had faced the same problem, now on adding the 2nd callback URL, it's fixed.

For more information check: https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342

Comment: Hey yes, I tried same. Adding a second one as https://mysitecom/auth/twitter/callback fixed for a 10mins. Now experiencing same problem. What url do you exactly give? Thanks!

Comment: @Designer what url you added in callback ?

Comment: mysitedotcom/ and mysitedotcom/auth/twitter/callback and both with h t t p s

Comment: Someone better fire an issue at Omniauth repo

Comment: @Designer try callback url: http://mysitedotcom/users/auth/twitter/callback and https://mysitedotcom/users/auth/twitter/callback, you must have to add 2 urls

Comment: @puneet18, using the same callback url results in error: "The client application failed validation: The default callback url should not be redundantly included in additional callback urls." Any definitive solution to this yet?

Answer (score 4):

Adding a second Callback URL to https://mysitecom/auth/twitter/callback fixed the issue (for now)

———-

Update: This actually solved the problem for about 10mins. Experiencing the same problem now

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. Can you expand on what you did?

Comment: This actually solved the problem for about like 10mins. Now experiencing same problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm working in development not production and encountered this problem using the omniauth and omniauth-twitter gems. But with these two callback URL's:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000
http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback
```

the problem is avoided. Strange, since the RailsApps tutorial warns against using 'localhost' at Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the issue by putting `https://domain/oauths/callback` in the Callback URLs list. Make sure you enable the callback locking option.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly related to this change: [Action REQUIRED - Sign in with Twitter users must whitelist callback URLs](https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342).

From the link:

> In 30 days, we will begin enforcing the whitelist such that any URL
>   not added to the whitelist will fail. This means that URLs can no
>   longer be programmatically overridden in calls to the
>   oauth/request_token endpoint 112. The callback_url parameter provided
>   must match one of the whitelisted callback URLs. While we generally
>   provide longer than a 30-day notice for changes like this, this
>   timeline allows us to continue to provide a safe and secure experience
>   for developers and our users.
>
> You can add callback URLs to your whitelist on the applications
>   settings page on apps.twitter.com 488.
>
> Enable the setting “Enable Callback Locking” to test that only URLs
>   you have whitelisted are accepted. Callback URLs will automatically be
>   locked and the whitelist will be enforced starting on June 12th. The
>   “Enable Callback Locking” setting will be removed on this date.

I could not get this to work in development with `127.0.0.1` so I ended up creating a DNS `A` record that pointed to `127.0.0.1` (e.g., `dev.example.com`) and used that in the callback url settings on https://apps.twitter.com.

[image: settings]

Answer (score 0):

Unicode domain name. Twitter give me error: unsupportable domain name format. I need exactly match callback url, sending by my server and callback url in my twitter app.
Solution:
config/initialization/twitter.rb

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter.class_eval do
  def callback_url
    return my_custom_twitter_app_callback_url_string_variable
  end
end
```

Comment: my_custom_twitter_app_callback_url_string_variable = 'http://my.ip.ad.res/auth/twitter/callback'