# Is there a working Devise/Omniauth/Oauth2 interface with Wordpress?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, oauth-2.0, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to use Wordpress to authenticate my Rails application users with the following Omniauth plugin:

https://github.com/jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin

I've followed the instructions carefully, and duplicated his example, but it doesn't work. Which is really surprising, because there's just not that much to it. However, I've found several threads on here like this one, that talk about the same problem I have:

[Devise, OmniAuth & Facebook: "Not found. Authentication passthru."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812844/devise-omniauth-facebook-not-found-authentication-passthru)

When I click the "Sign in with Wordpress" (which is automatically inserted in my Devise sign-in page), I simply get a 404, with "Not found. Authentication passthru," which is a stub response for the `passthru` method in the Devise sources. Routes rake just fine, and look like all the examples. I've restarted the server dozens of times.

Despite several attempts to set `site:` and `authorization_url:` in the `client_options`, in both my devise config, and the plugin sources directly, my app never redirects to my Wordpress site. I've got about 10 hours into screwing around with this, and I don't know what's supposed to be responsible for actually sending me to the site to DO the authentication. Further complicating figuring this out is that almost every reference I can find to redirection in this sort of scenario is about the *callback* to my Rails site, after the authentication is done. I can never get that far.

There's a lot of confusing references to this problem on SO and the internet at large. There's some talk about making a "real" `passthru` or `action_missing` method in my OmniauthCallbacksController, but that seems to be outdated information. There's a lot of talk about making sure that I've defined the `omniauth_providers` in my User model, and I've tried it with and without, but that's not in any of the documentation about this plugin.

I've been trying to look at the plugin's strategy file, and it just doesn't seem that different than other Oauth2 plugins for Facebook, Google, or whatever, that I've been reviewing. It seems like there's a very simple thing I need to set in order to make this all work, but I can't find it, and I've run out of ideas on how to track it down. The plugin was last updated about 5 years ago. Does anyone still use this with modern versions of Devise, Omniauth, and Wordpress? If so, is there a clue you can give me to make it work?

Comment: I've installed the Facebook strategy, and that directs me to their site to do the authentication, so I can see that my "stack" is basically functional. However, if I stick a `binding.pry` in the Omniauth code at various places, I can see that the request_phase is never called on the Wordpress strategy, and I can't fathom why. I've created a request_phase override method on the strategy, and it's never called either. I'm utterly lost to understand why the Facebook strategy will direct me, but the Wordpress one won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally started tracing through the gem, and found where it was failing. As I searched on those further problems, I finally figured out that there were about 25 forks of this gem, and many of them addressed the problem. I used this particular one: https://github.com/bkno/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin